# How can I save output of a shell command in fluentd config?

Tags: fluentd

I have a `fluent.conf` file. I want to execute a shell command and use the output in a `<filter>` and a `<match>` (for output).

E.g.

```
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    some_data <output_from_command>
  </record>
</filter>

<match **>
  <use_same_command_output_here>
</match>
```

For obvious reasons, I want it to run *once*, at config eval time, and not with each event.

Do I just use some form of the Ruby inline with `"#{...}"`?